# How to parallelize for-loops?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, parallel-processing

I'm working on a project where I have multiple queries to extract data from Elasticsearch.

I want to query from two different indexes in Elasticsearch simultaneously and in very short time (real-time use case).
What should I do to improve the loop time and to parallelize my two `for` loops.
This is a part of my code:

```
t2 = time.time()

for i in range(docs_enter):
    enter_t = req_enter['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['Time']
    enter_time = datetime.strptime(enter_t,time_format)
    total_duration = now - enter_time
    if total_duration < threshold_hours:
        enter_face = req_enter['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['FaceID']
        enter_img = np.array(enter_face).astype(np.uint8)
        match_enter = verifyFace(crop, enter_img)
        acc_enter.append(match_enter)

t3 = time.time()

for j in range(docs_guichet):
    guichet_t = req_guichet['hits']['hits'][j]['_source']['Time']
    guichet_time = datetime.strptime(guichet_t,time_format)
    total_duration = now - guichet_time
    if total_duration < threshold_hours:
        guichet_face = req_guichet['hits']['hits'][j]['_source']['FaceID']
        guichet_img = np.array(guichet_face).astype(np.uint8)
        match_guichet = verifyFace(crop, guichet_img)
        acc_guichet.append(match_guichet)

t4 = time.time()

print(f"\n------ 1st loop time {t3 - t2} -------\n")
print(f"\n------ 2nd loop time {t4 - t3} -------\n")
```

And this is the elapsed time for these two loops :

[image]

What should I do to:

1. Improve the loop time
2. Parallelize the two for loops

Comment: You can use multi threading.

Comment: @Goion I've tried that but nothing have been changed !

Comment: then perhaps you didn't implement it correctly.